# Is the diameter an invariant in General Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

How can you define diameter in General Relativity? How would you calculate it for a given fixed $r$ in spherical coordinates in Minkowski and Schwarzschild metrics?

I've seen somewhere that "In differential geometry, the diameter is an important global Riemannian invariant". [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diameter]. Is it true? Why? Would it extend to GR? If not, how do you calculate the maximum distance between two points contained in a hypersphere of radius $r$ for the usual metrics (Mink. & Schw.)? Wouldn't it be infinite? (You can pick very distant t coordinates).

Comment: The diameter refered to in that article is the diameter of the entire space, not the diameter of some object located inside the space. Accordingly, it's an invariant of the space. It's not defined for all Riemannian manifolds (and certainly not for all semi-Riemannian ones, like used in GR).